# Sandhyavandanam: sitting or squatting?

Tags: sandhyavandanam

I see two types of sandhyavandanam: performed while sitting and performed while squatting. Smarthas usually sit while sri vaishnavas usually squat. Which scriptures are each practice based on? It looks to me like squatting is done simply to avoid sitting on a dirty ground.

Comment: Squatting is also a sitting posture .. when one does not have an asana to sit upon one usually squats ... According to the Ahnika Krityam book any ritual which is to be done while sitting can also be done while in the praurapada posture (squatting posture).

Comment: @Rickross Can sandhyavandanam be done sitting on the floor in padmasana?

Comment: First spread a mat/Asana (preferably made of wool or Kusha) and then sit on it. Directly sitting on the floor while performing any ritual is not recommended.

Comment: one has to stand up for arghyam, japa, upasthanam, vandanam etc. very small time spent sitting. sayam sandhi japa can be done sitting, but most others standing

Comment: @mar Correct but what about the beginning, especially achamanam? Squatting is uncomfortable for my knees.

Comment: squatting is actually part of yogic asana.. in fact that is the pose for healthy ashoucha too. it's cos u're used to western uknow..  :)

Comment: @mar Oh yeah true, but what is the alternative to squatting for achamanam? And it's not just westerners, but even old people who have failing knees and arthritis. I have seen in mathams. So there is definitely an alternative. I suppose I can sit just like many smarthas do.

Comment: Achamana must be done only while being seated if it is being done on the ground. Only time it is allowed to be performed while standing is when one is inside water. That's why Achamana should be done sitting on an Asana or in the squatting position .. Note that squatting position is considered as a siting posture @Ikshvaku

Comment: @Rickross Ok, thanks